# Filling sensor_msgs/Image with uint8_t buffer array

Tags: camera, opencv2, cv-bridge, image, sensor-msgs#image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I'm working on making a camera driver, and the data struct contains the frame data such as the height and width, and uint8_t leftData  and uint8_t rightData pointers. Ive been trying to see which way would be the best way to just fill simple fill in the sensor_msgs/Image message i create, but i cannot seem to find how to do it.

Here is what i have tried so far:

```
    leftImage.height                = pFrameData->height;
    leftImage.width                 = pFrameData->width;
    leftImage.encoding              = sensor_msgs::image_encodings::MONO8;
    leftImage.step                  = 64;
    leftImage.data                  = pFrameData->leftData;
```

But with that i get a error saying "no viable overloaded '=' "

Then after searching around i found people linking to the sensor_msgs::fillImage() header, and tried to use the memcpy method, but that did not work either (i got a seg fault)

Then i tried using the cv::Mat constructor to see if i could at LEAST somehow get a image to publish, by passing the size, type, and data pointer (pFrameData->leftData).

No luck with any of them. Im really new to opencv, cv_bridge, and camera related things in general. Would someone be able to guide me in the right direction?

Here is a example buffer for the left camera if i just print to the screen: `0x7ff7549ea800`

*EDIT 1:*

Here is my frame callback function (after trying ahendrix's solution, which gave a malloc error which i put in comments below):

```
void frameCallback(const PFrame pFrameData)
{
    leftImage.header.stamp            = ros::Time::now();
    leftImage.header.frame_id       = "camera";
    leftImage.height                      = pFrameData->height;
    leftImage.width                       = pFrameData->width;
    leftImage.encoding                  = sensor_msgs::image_encodings::MONO8;
    leftImage.step                         = 64;

    const int image_size = pFrameData->height * pFrameData->width;
    leftImage.data.reserve(image_size);

    for( int i=0; i < image_size; i++ )
    {
            leftImage.data.push_back(pFrameData->leftData[i]); 
    }
 }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196167/filling-sensor_msgs/image-with-uint8_t-buffer-array/) by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1526 on 2014-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So after @ahendrix helped explaining a few things, i ended up using the sensor_msgs::fillImage() function to store my left/right camera buffer data into a sensor_msgs::Image.

Here is my code:

```
    ros::Time       timeNow         = ros::Time::now();
    std::string     frame           = "camera";

    leftImage.header.stamp          = timeNow;
    leftImage.header.frame_id       = frame;

    rightImage.header.stamp         = timeNow;
    rightImage.header.frame_id      = frame;

    // Fill the left image message
    sensor_msgs::fillImage( leftImage,
                            sensor_msgs::image_encodings::MONO8,
                            240, // height
                            320, // width
                            320, // stepSize
                            pFrameData->leftData);

    // Fill the right image message
    sensor_msgs::fillImage( rightImage,
                            sensor_msgs::image_encodings::MONO8,
                            240, // height
                            320, // width
                            320, // stepSize
                            pFrameData->rightData);

    leftImagePub.publish(leftImage);
    rightImagePub.publish(rightImage);

    sensor_msgs::clearImage(leftImage);
    sensor_msgs::clearImage(rightImage);
```

If you look in the [sensor_msgs::fillImage()](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/sensor_msgs/html/fill__image_8h_source.html#l00044) the step size (in my case) was the width of the image; the total amount of *columns* your image has.

inside the fillImage() you will see that a size_t st0 is created by multiplying the step size (which we said is the width) * rows (height of the image), which will create a size and then allocate the *total amount of pixels your image has*.

---

Originally posted by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) with karma: 1526 on 2014-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The array members in messages are `std::vector`s. I suspect your image data is a pointer to a buffer, and you can't assign from a pointer into a std::vector; you'll have to copy the data manually. (This is what the 'no viable overload' message is trying to tell you)

Something like this might work:

```
const int image_size = pFrameData->height * pFrameData->width;
leftImage.data.reserve(image_size);
for( int i=0; i < image_size; i++ ) {
    leftImage.data.push_back(pFrameData->leftData[i]); // do pixel format translation here if necessary
}
```

Of course, this assumes that your image buffer is in the same format as the output image. If it isn't, you'll have to do some sort of conversion.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-10-29**:
Can i use the sensor_msgs/fillImage inline function? I tried to use that last night to, well i manually copied in the size allocation, and memcpy, but that was what i got the set fault on. Since its a inline i assumed it would've have been the same thing as just including the header. Correct?

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-10-29**:
so i just tried that and i still got a seg fault, and the next time i tried to run the node i got this error "
malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd0e0d12a30: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-29**:
I hadn't seen [sensor_msgs::fillImage()](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/sensor_msgs/html/namespacesensor__msgs.html#a095073651e9caa2f887e395c8e8d3dbb) before. That's probably a better choice.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-29**:
That said, you're setting the step size to 64, which implies that each pixel is 64 bytes. That isn't consistent with a MONO8 ecoding...

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-10-29**:
This probably might make a difference idk, but i don't think the step size should 64, in the documentation of the camera it says the leftData pointer and rightData pointer are *aligned* to 64 byte boundaries. Not sure what that means

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-10-29**:
64-byte aligned refers to where data is placed in memory. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment